# Magento 2: what are the benefits of using service contracts?

Tags: api, magento-2.0, service-contract, factory, crud

So as some of you may know, Magento 2 recommended way to deal with models/collections for CRUD actions is to use service contracts.

But still according to the Magento SE Q&A it seems like most people tend to use the model/resource model/collection directly instead.

As an example to load a quote I can do it directly via the factory like this:

```
$this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
```

Where `$this->quoteFactory` is an instance of `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory`

But I can also do it via service contract like this:

```
$this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
```

Where `$this->quoteRepository` is an instance of `\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface`

So my questions is **what are the benefits of using service contracts over factories ?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Benifits of using service contracts, (as per Magento 2 understanding)

Service contracts have a number of important functions for Magento 2, such as:

- Upgrading modules becomes easy.
- Simplify customizations to the module without digging into the core files.
- Reduce the conflict between modules in the system.
- Magento upgrades are safer using service contract.
- For services will remain unchanged within the new releases of it, making upgrade in future are easy for existing module.
- For model/collections this case are not true within new releases.

Answer (score 5):

I think the greatest benefit is that modules can determine which functionality can be used by other modules. In Magento 1 you had helpers that where often kind of misused for this purpose (but that's a whole other discussen), but in Magento 2 your module can provide functionality to other modules (for example by 3rd party developers) and have it separated and self-contained.

Dependency Injection provides a system where you can use an interface in your construction so you only have access to those public methods.

Some examples:

Want to link a product to multiple categories? Use `\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface`:

```
$this->categoryLinkManagement->assignProductToCategories(
    $sku,
    $categoryIds
);
```

Want to increase a products' stock quantity? Use `Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockManagementInterface`:

```
$this->stockManagement->backItemQty(
    $productId,
    $itemsToReceive
);
```

These two example show perfectly the proper use of service contracts. Besides that, they provide a uniform interface to communicate with:

- Other Modules (as described above)
- Console Commands
- API Calls
- etc.

Answer (score 2):

Benefits of service contract:

- Enhance the modularity of Magento
- Ensure a well-defined, durable API that other modules and third-party extensions can implement
- Make it easy to configure services as web APIs.
- Data entities  reveal a simpler data model than the data model in an underlying relational database schema
- Use different storage technologies for different data collections