# Magento 2 API vs. Web Interface vs. Web API

Tags: magento2, api, web-services, service-contract, interface

Just as a basic question in Magento 2. 
In Magento U tutorials, it says:

> In Magento 2 Modules only communicate through API
>
> One module in not aware of the internals of another, so the
>   implementation can change.
>
> Modules can be disabled or deployed on separate servers.

I don't get what it means by **"Magento 2 modules only communicate through API"** ? If I want to load products, how we are using APIs without knowing?

I need a little bit explanation about interface vs. API interface vs. Web API. Is there any difference ? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular statement, API refers to service contracts. It is different than web APIs.

> A service contract is a set of PHP interfaces that are defined for a
>   module. A service contract includes data interfaces, which preserve
>   data integrity, and service interfaces, which hide business logic
>   details from service requestors such as controllers, web services, and
>   other modules.

[image]

You can find more information regarding service contracts in the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html

On the other hand, here is the official doc for the Web API: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html

Finally regarding your question to load products, I reckon you should check that question that highlights the benefits of using service contracts: [Magento 2: what are the benefits of using service contracts?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115398/magento-2-what-are-the-benefits-of-using-service-contracts)