# How can I get a product's image URL using service contracts?

Tags: magento2, api, image, product-images, service-contract

I know that in Magento 2.0, [there is a recommended way to access products info from another module using service contracts](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115398/magento-2-what-are-the-benefits-of-using-service-contracts).

So, my first question: **how can I get a product's image URL using service contracts and an API function**?

Second question: I want to **override product's possible "getImageUrl" function so that I can generate a custom URL (points to an external source) and return it back as Image URL**. So, any other external or internal module that wants to access a product's image's URL will get my generated URL instead of Magento's default product Image URL. Should it be implemented using service contracts ? Because its the recommended way in Magento 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first question, I reckon you should use `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementInterface`

Usual process you need to first inject the class in your constructor:

```
protected $_productMediaGalleryInterface;

public __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementInterface $productMediaGalleryInterface
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_productMediaGalleryInterface = $productMediaGalleryInterface;
    ...
}
```

Then in your class, based on the product sku you can retrieve the list of gallerie entries associated with the given product:

```
$galleryEntries = $this->_productMediaGalleryInterface->getList($sku);
```

However, I'm pretty sure this won't give you all the data and maybe just a list of gallery entries.

To get information about a gallery entry you can call:

```
$galleryEntryData = this->_productMediaGalleryInterface->get($sku, $entryId);
```

**Regarding your second question, I should you should use plugins.**

Indeed, the `getImageUrl` is a public method for both `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product` and `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Gallery`

Thus using a plugin with `after` statement you should be able to change the product image URL in a clean way.

I'm not too sure how service contracts would be relevant in that case. **Service contracts are relevant when you add new type of database entities via a module and you need to do simple CRUD operations**.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I thought using service contracts we can even replace Magento's entire product functionality with something else (like connecting it to a NoSQL data structure). Is it really possible ?

Comment: @MichelGokan I'm not sure that's a whole another question. I suggest you mark this question as answered and open a new one ;)