# How to get disabled products in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, programmatically

Is there a way to **get disabled products programmatically in Magento 2** ?

Answer (score 6):

You can try with:

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $_productCollectionFactory **/

$this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
```

Need to inject `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $_productCollectionFactory` in your constructor.

Answer (score 4):

It's best practice to use the Service Contracts Layer (see here: [Magento 2: what are the benefits of using service contracts?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/115398/2380))

```
protected $_productRepository;

protected $_searchCriteriaBuilder;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
) {
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
}
```

Then in your code you can do:

```
$searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED, 'eq')->create();
$searchResults = $this->_productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
$disabledProducts = $searchResults->getItems();
```