# M2 Include disabled products in product list widget collection

Tags: magento2, product-collection

- I'm not sure if this is an m2 2.2 bug or just due the way I'm trying to filter the collection, 
  but I can't seem to include disabled products in my product list collection.
- I've tried a few different options from what I've seen in a few forum posts.
- The below code snippet is purely to retrieve disabled products (as a first step, though the aim is to have enabled and disabled products).
- This code results in zero products listed despite having disabled products which meet the criteria. Trying here in case there's something glaringly obvious I'm missing or a known bug with m2 2.2 requiring a workaround.

  ```
         $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
  //$collection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

  $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
      ->addStoreFilter()
      ->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED)
      ->setCurPage($this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getData('page_var_name'), 1));

  $conditions = $this->getConditions();
  $conditions->collectValidatedAttributes($collection);
  $this->sqlBuilder->attachConditionToCollection($collection, $conditions);

  return $collection;
  ```

My widget is extended from: 
`class ProductsList extends \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') //all attributes
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);

//print all collection
foreach($collection as $product){
   echo $product->getName(). "<br>";
}
```

[Ref](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147256/how-to-get-disabled-products-in-magento-2)

Comment: Hi @Adarsh - thanks for this. I'd tried this already and it only outputs one product, when I know there are other disabled products it should output.

Comment: I can confirm it is working in my instance. Showing me all the disabled products.

Comment: Ok it may be specific to my instance in that case - thanks, will check it out locally!